# BASH: Progres Bar

Tags: centos6

I want write a little progress bar for another script. On my Mac it works perfect, but on my CENTOS 6 Server it doesn't work. It comes the error "sleep: invalid time interval „1\r“
„sleep --help“ for more information"

Here is my script:

```
echo -ne "[*###############]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[#*##############]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[##*#############]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[###*############]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[####*###########]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[#####*##########]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[######*#########]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[#######*########]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[########*#######]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[#########*######]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[##########*#####]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[###########*####]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[############*###]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[#############*##]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[##############*#]\r"
sleep 1
echo -ne "[###############]\r"
```

Comment: Try changing you end of line from "\r" to "\n" (for the file not for the `echo`).

Comment: Where exactly? Can you show me?

Comment: see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/687077/159717) @superuser